# Removing specific values from database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to remove some data from my database, and I need help with my SQL.
Basically this is the result I want to get in my Java code:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE name = '***specific value from combobox***'
```

With INSERT I did this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Table2 (name) values (?)";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String name = ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
pst.setString(1, name);
```

Now I want to use DELETE instead of insert, something like this:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE name =  values (?)";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String name = ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
pst.setString(1, name);
```

I need help with the SQL string.

Comment: Slightly O/T, but Is there a reason why one would want to do a string search on values from a combobox, which will always either be only values from a small, constant subset, or a value from a very small, constant subset plus some other values? I think this calls for normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update this line.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE name = ?";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the delete SQL to this:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE name = ?";
```

"values" is part of the `INSERT` statement only, where you are declaring the values of the row you will insert. It is not needed in the `DELETE` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
 String sql = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE name = ?";
```